# minecraft is there a way to make a kill aura hack with commands? 1.15.2 / 1.16

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to make hack ish like 'Kill aura', in vanilla Minecraft, Using only command blocks?
(Kill aura is like an aim bot, it hits all nearby hostile mobs automatically!)

Is there a simple way for me to do it? I'd prefer to have a single command to copy and paste.
Do you have some ideas, or is it impossible to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite simple, in a repeat command block, put this command:

`/execute at YourPlayerName run effect give @e[distance=1..5] instant_damage 1 1 true`.

This would also ignore armor, and should make it so that you don't take any damage. It will also target all players (and mobs) around you.

Edit: this command will pretty much instakill ANYTHING near you, so instead, put it in a redstone loop that activates only every so often, OR you can just make it wither, by using `wither 1 1` instead of `instant_damage 1 1`.

Comment: okay but with that it will do the same damage even if the player are holding a diamond sword with sharpness 5 and fire aspect!